# Passing a VectorXi from eigen library to class method

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, eigen

The following main file should pass a VectorXi to my class called `Test` which then has a method that does something with it (for demonstration it just prints the sum of all elements):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    VectorXi m(3);
    m[0] = 1;
    m[1] = 2;
    m[2] = 6;

    Test test;
    test.mySum(m);

    return 0;
}
```

The test.h

```
#ifndef __CPP_Playground__test__
#define __CPP_Playground__test__

#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class Test {
public:
    void mySum(VectorXi vec); // Does not work. 
//    void mySum(VectorXi vec){cout << vec.sum() << endl;}; // Works.
};

#endif /* defined(__CPP_Playground__test__) */
```

and the test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void mySum(VectorXi vec){
    cout << vec.sum() << endl;
};
```

When compiling with Xcode 6.1.1 on OS X 10.10.2 I get the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Test::mySum(Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to use `libstdc++` instead of `libc++` under the project settings but it didn't work. I installed the eigen library using Homebrew via `brew install eigen`. Why is it working with the method directly defined in test.h (see commented line) but not when it is defined in the test.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Eigen, you simply omitted the class prefix `Test::` in the cpp file:

```
void Test::mySum(VectorXi vec){
    cout << vec.sum() << endl;
}
```

Moreover, the trailing `;` was not needed in proper C++, and you should rather pass the `vec` object by reference declaring the argument as `VectorXi &vec` or even better use a `Eigen::Ref<VectorXi> vec` to allow compatible objects to be passed by reference.